# QGIS Atlas attribute

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a little problem when create atlas with QGIS but I'm new and I have a step by step explanation.

I have a shapefile with 2 columns `a` and `b`:

```
a     b    
1     abc
2     cde
3     abc
4     efg
5     abc
```

I need create atlas with only `b` attributes, without double values. Any suggestions?

The atlas must be have 3 pages.

With "abc", "cde" and "efg" not 5 pages one for line.

I send you 2 pictures, what I mean lose some polygons. The first is the original shape, the second is the dissolved shape. You can see there aren't some polygons. I don't understand why.

[image: Original shape]

[image: Dissolved shape]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you elaborate more what you mean by "double values"?

Answer (score 1):

You must to convert your layer to another layer without doubles..

For example, you could use "Dissolve" tool.

And then, you'll do the atlas with the new layer.

Comment: I have try to use dissove tool but i don't understand, why I lose some polygons of my shape.

Comment: Don't lose polygons, dissolve tool agregate polygons

Comment: Ok, I see. You have a topological errors. You should to "clean" your layer. pe GRASS v.clean (tool "bpol").

Comment: I never use GRASS and I don't know it... I must open "QGIS Desktop 2.18.2 with GRASS 7.0.5"?

Comment: Yes, you must to open QGIS with GRASS. Open "Processing", active GRASS in options and find v.Clean in Toolbox.

Comment: Ok, I run the tool ... makes me 3 polygons vector, 1 line vector and 1 point vector... are right?

Comment: @Davide please do not edit an answer when you wish to provide more info.  Rather edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: @Davide I have moved your edits to this answer into your original question.

Comment: Carlos is right, run dissolve on that layer with column b selected. This will create multi-polygons. On atlas, they will one create one page.